# How do I get Flask to work with a private XAMPP server?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, xampp

This is the first time I've used Flask outside of a learning environment. (I've recently installed it on Windows.) Not only is Flask not rendering my index.html template, but nothing appears on my browser.

I'm starting simple, just to make sure Flask is working.

`#!D:\Python311\python.exe`

`print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")`

`from flask import Flask, render_template`

`app = Flask(__name__)`

`print(__name__)`

As I've seen it done in examples, I tried debugging by using a print statement for `__name__`, expecting it to result in something like `__main__`. The page is still blank. The file index.html is inside a folder called "templates," since I learned that's what you need to do when working with render_template.

I'm wondering now if maybe I installed Flask in a bad place, but I followed the instructions given on their website for their latest version pretty closely. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance! C: